# How do I get a JavaScript popup to come without clicking link?

Tags: javascript

I am using some pre-written JavaScript from polldaddy.

They have a JavaScript option which, when you click on the link, the survey pops up as an overlay to my site.

However, I would like when people come to the site, the overlay comes up on its own without needing to click on the link.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var PDF_surveyID = 'F1B4CE39FE1ECE86';
 var PDF_openText = 'View Survey';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.polldaddy.com/s.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://surveys.polldaddy.com/s/F1B4CE39FE1ECE86/">View Survey</a></noscript>
```

Comment: You also might want to consider setting a cookie when an individual has completed the survey so that it doesn't appear every time they come to your site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at http://www.polldaddy.com/s.js, the link is written is in the following statement:

```
document.write('<a href="javascript:PDF_launch(\''+ PDF_surveyID +'\');">'+ PDF_openText +'</a>');
```

So when you click on the link, it's calling

```
PDF_launch(PDF_surveyID);
```

What you'll want to do is call this yourself when the page loads. For example:

```
<body onload="PDF_launch(PDF_surveyID)">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the script you're including, you'll see it does this:

```
document.write('<a href="javascript:PDF_launch(\''+ PDF_surveyID +'\');">'+ PDF_openText +'</a>');
```

to put the link into the page. What you'll want to do, then, is call `PDF_launch` when the page loads.